# Does Mongoose upsert operation update/renew default schema values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose Schema:

```
new Schema({
    ...
    createDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updateDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Upsert operation:

```
const upsertDoc = {
...
}

Model.update({ key: 123 }, upsertDoc, { upsert: true })
```

when I upsert  with `update` or `findOneAndUpdate` the default schema values `createDate` and `updateDate` are always renewed no matter document is inserted or updated. It's same when I use `$set` (in which of course I don't pass dates).

I don't seem to find anything to tell if it's an expected behavior. I expect dates to be added only on insert and not update, unless explicitly set.

Comment: Hi Talha Awan - can I ask you to clarify something? Are you using the [timestamps option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) in your schema?

Comment: @VinceBowdren, nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for "proof" of the expected behavior, then look no further than the source code itself. Particularly within the [`schema.js` main definition](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/0fe5f2a5a02aff8c52e4583f62f845a1d013e4f9/lib/schema.js#L832-L863):

```
        updates.$setOnInsert = {};
        updates.$setOnInsert[createdAt] = now;
      }

      return updates;
    };

    this.methods.initializeTimestamps = function() {
      if (createdAt && !this.get(createdAt)) {
        this.set(createdAt, new Date());
      }
      if (updatedAt && !this.get(updatedAt)) {
        this.set(updatedAt, new Date());
      }
      return this;
    };

    this.pre('findOneAndUpdate', _setTimestampsOnUpdate);
    this.pre('update', _setTimestampsOnUpdate);
    this.pre('updateOne', _setTimestampsOnUpdate);
    this.pre('updateMany', _setTimestampsOnUpdate);
  }

  function _setTimestampsOnUpdate(next) {
    var overwrite = this.options.overwrite;
    this.update({}, genUpdates(this.getUpdate(), overwrite), {
      overwrite: overwrite
    });
    applyTimestampsToChildren(this);
    next();
  }
```

So there you can see all the `'pre'` middleware handlers being registered for each of the "update" method variants and to the same functional code. These all essentially modify the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in any "update" you issue to include the `updatedAt` field, or whatever name you mapped to that key in the schema options.

The actual statement sent with "upsert" actions uses [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) for the `createdAt` field or mapped option name ( see the top of the listing ). This action **only** applies when an "upsert" actually occurs, so documents that exist and are merely matches for any of the "update" methods are **never** actually touched by this value.

Those operators are part of how MongoDB works and not really to do with mongoose, but the code shown here shows how mongoose "adjusts" your "update" actions in order to include these additional operations.

For reference the whole main function in `schema.js` which works out what to apply currently begins at [Line #798](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/0fe5f2a5a02aff8c52e4583f62f845a1d013e4f9/lib/schema.js#L798) for the `genUpdates()` function as called in the bottom part of the listing shown here yet the top part is the last few lines of that function where the keys of [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) get defined.

So in summary, YES every "update" action is intentional that the `updatedAt` mapped field has the current `Date` value assigned, and also that the "updates" are modified to include the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) action which **only** applies when a new document is created as the result of an "upsert" action for the `createdAt` mapped field.

Comment: Thorough and in-depth answer as always. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Neil; I might have misunderstood, but it looks like the code you have described is concerned with the [timestamps option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps), but the question is about [defaults](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html), which operate differently - is that right?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I think the point here is understanding the difference between `$set` and `$setOnInsert`. Believing in "mongoose magic" is the sort of thing that get's the OP and many others into all sorts of trouble because they don't understand what this "simple options setting" actually does. If you take the time to explain it to people, then they might actually understand "why" to do things that way. Besides, OP just spent 100 rep. Should get a better response then RTFM should they not?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd always recommend to use the provided and recommended way to manage `createdAt` and `updatedAt` by mongoose. Simply by passing `timeStamp: true` as schema options.

This is always a best practice and lets you not to be worried about such behaviors.

I use it and I never see a problem with timestamps using `update` or `findOneAndUpdate`.

Here is how you use it

```
 new Schema({
   ... //Your schema
 },{ timestamps: true})
```